# How to return images to devices from server on device specifications

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I have an application , which is doing so good. But the main problem is the app size as I am using the so many images because app is all about showing some images. SO to cut down the app size , I am making app with some demo images let say 5 to 10 images. Then I have decided to let the user download new images from the server and use them later.

**What I am doing :**

For testing purpose this thing is also working good. Now the real question is , I need to maintain the images on server with category. and I will send device dpi category , let say hdi , mdpi , or tvdpi from the device . Here is the code How I am getting the dpi,

```
 switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            // ...
            phoneVersion = "low_dpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            // ...
            phoneVersion = "medium_dpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            phoneVersion = "high_dpi";
            // ...
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            phoneVersion = "xhigh_dpi";
            // ...
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
            phoneVersion = "tv_dpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            phoneVersion = "xx_dpi";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            phoneVersion = "xxx_dpi";
            break;


    }
```

**What is problem :**

I have confusion  that what should I send to server  and in which manner I should maintain images by category . 
 Here is example , 
I have a device name Samsung 10 inch tablet having resolution of 800*1200 and the dpi it has is Medium dpi , where as on the other hand , there is a small device , which has resolution of 320*480 having medium dpi also

**More questions :**

So what should I do to get the exactly the type of images as Android os decides when images are being saved in its resource folder.

1. what mechanism should I select to get the images according to device size and dpis.
2. how many resolutions of images should I made and save on server if I want to cover all devices

Please help me , this is the last point in my app. I have no more code to share as this is the just about taking the best idea from you guys. What you think what should I do?

Comment: how about dpi and device type

Comment: what do you man by that

Comment: device type = normal , large, xlarge